# Adding % sign in label values

Tags: iphone, ipad, uilabel

how to add % sign to label value i ma using following code for setting value on label

```
        deathLabelOne.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",r_Fatal_NV];
```

I want label after this values

```
     I have tried like this 


        deathLabelOne.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f%",r_Fatal_NV];
```

but this is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the fact that it's a label, it's the fact that it's a format string - you'll have this problem anywhere you use a format string.  The representation for a percent sign in a format string is `%%`.  So you want this:

```
deathLabelOne.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f%%",r_Fatal_NV];
```

For more details, see [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).